# installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl357092003.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #18): <activity> does not have valid android:name]

Tags: android, while-loop, installation, apk

I have a problem with android Studio 2.2.3 
when I try to run my simpleproject , hello world app , iget this error
[the first problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLQzV.png)

then I clicked ok .

I get a new problem

[the second problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loobg.png)

what's the solution

Comment: Add you xml code here

Comment: looks like you have errors in your manifest

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml? I reckon you've got an invalid character in `<activity android:name />`

Comment: that's the AndroidManifest xml

Answer (score 0):

```
that's the code of AndroidManifest xml :     








<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```